# Difference in linear model, but not in either main-effects

Tags: r, regression, t-test, linear-model

My experiment is a 3 (auditory, vibe, multimodal) x 2 (simple, metro) design. I am defining a linear regression model, using contrast codes (-1,1) to compare means between conditions. I am also looking at main effects using post-hoc t-tests

```
#contrasts
MetronomeSimple <- c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)
AuditoryVibe <- c(1,0,-1,1,0,-1)
AuditoryMultimodal <- c(-1,1,0,-1,1,0)
AuditorySimpleVibeSimple <- c(0,0,0,1,0,-1)
contrasts(entrain_df$trials) <- cbind(MetronomeSimple,
                                      AuditoryVibe,
                                      AuditoryMultimodal,
                                      AuditorySimpleVibeSimple)
#model 
ENlinear <- lm(en1 ~ trials, data = entrain_df)
summary(ENlinear)
```

I am getting some weird findings. I get a significant difference p < 0.01, for the the AuditoryMultimodal contrast. However, when I examine the main effects using post-hoc t-tests I do not find a significant difference in either of the conditions

```
#model summery 
lm(formula = en1 ~ trials, data = entrain_df)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.081664 -0.021471 -0.008251  0.017213  0.108259 

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)                     0.0686584  0.0028161
trialsMetronomeSimple           0.0084093  0.0028161
trialsAuditoryVibe              0.0176878  0.0051962
trialsAuditoryMultimodal        0.0098270  0.0039958
trialsAuditorySimpleVibeSimple -0.0091532  0.0068751
trials                          0.0001544  0.0069209
                               t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     24.381  < 2e-16 ***
trialsMetronomeSimple            2.986 0.003325 ** 
trialsAuditoryVibe               3.404 0.000862 ***
trialsAuditoryMultimodal         2.459 0.015112 *  
trialsAuditorySimpleVibeSimple  -1.331 0.185192    
trials                           0.022 0.982233    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03436 on 143 degrees of freedom
  (7 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1349,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1046 
F-statistic: 4.458 on 5 and 143 DF,  p-value: 0.0008351
```

```
t.test(multiSimple$en1,audSimple$en1, na.action = na.omit)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  multiSimple$en1 and audSimple$en1
t = 1.2224, df = 41.533, p-value = 0.2285
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.007157514  0.029128954
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
0.06998692 0.05900120 

> t.test(multiMetro$en1,audMetro$en1, na.action = na.omit)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  multiMetro$en1 and audMetro$en1
t = 0.19227, df = 46.028, p-value = 0.8484
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.01988436  0.02408416
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
0.08698381 0.08488391
```

This does not make sense to me. How can there be a large difference between the conditions but no differences in the main effects? Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: not very sure what happened without the data, but if you look at the other results in your summary, trialsMetronomeSimple and trialsAuditoryVibe are also significant. this means, if you don't account for these effect in the t.test, your standard error will be larger, leading to a lower t-stat..

Comment: this is the reason you do a multivariate regression... to take other factors into account. you can do a post doc using glht() in multcomp package, or emmeans